# How to count fraction numbers added to each other in one cell in Excel

Tags: excel

So I'm trying to count fraction numbers, added to each other in one Excel cell?

For instance:   =8.86+12.45+12.24...etc   so it can count it as 3?
Please help, and Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Excel you have. If you have Excel 2013, this formula counts the number of plus signs and adds 1:

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+",""))+1
```

If you have an earlier version, this User Defined Function might work for you. It takes one or more cells as its argument. If you're not familiar with UDFs, Chip Pearson has [good info on them](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx):

```
Public Function CountNums(rng As Excel.Range) As Long
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim NumCount As Long

For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(cell.Formula, "+") > 0 Then
        NumCount = NumCount + (Len(cell.Formula) - Len(Replace(cell.Formula, "+", ""))) + 1
    End If
Next cell
CountNums = NumCount
End Function
```

Comment: user3408620 You can also extend Doug answer to look for decimal points if you want to exclude whole numbers like 5 and focus only on fractions. e.g 3.14 + 5 + 2.5 (you have only 2 . for 3 values and 2 + signs). P.S. _Tip_: as a new SO user please click the arrow on left of answer to accept @doug-glancy's great answer